# WCF Service Method is not Working

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, wcf

I am currently working on wcf service and Service is running localhost.I have some methods in Wcf Service. I am facing some Errors when I want to access the method from localhost by typing for example http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent/
its shows following errors.

**

```
Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```

**
Here is my code form Wcf service....

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IStudentService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/GetAllStudent/")]
        List<StudentDataContract> GetAllStudent();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/GetStudentDetails/{StudentId}")]
        StudentDataContract GetStudentDetails(string StudentId);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/AddNewStudent")]
        bool AddNewStudent(StudentDataContract student);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/UpdateStudent")]
        void UpdateStudent(StudentDataContract contact);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "DeleteStudent/{StudentId}")]
        void DeleteStudent(string StudentId);

    }

}
```

Here is my code of Implementation ...

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        StudentManagementEntities ctx;

        public StudentService()
        {
            ctx = new StudentManagementEntities();
        }

        public List<StudentDataContract> GetAllStudent()
        {
            //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GetAllStudent")
            //    return null;

            var query = (from a in ctx.Students
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<StudentDataContract> studentList = new List<StudentDataContract>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
            {
                studentList.Add(new StudentDataContract
                {
                    StudentID = Convert.ToString(rec.StudentID),
                    Name = rec.Name,
                    Email = rec.Email,
                    EnrollYear = rec.EnrollYear,
                    Class = rec.Class,
                    City = rec.City,
                    Country = rec.Country
                });
            });
            return studentList;
        }

        public StudentDataContract GetStudentDetails(string StudentId)
        {
            StudentDataContract student = new StudentDataContract();

            try
            {
                int Emp_ID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
                var query = (from a in ctx.Students
                             where a.StudentID.Equals(Emp_ID)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

                student.StudentID = Convert.ToString(query.StudentID);
                student.Name = query.Name;
                student.Email = query.Email;
                student.EnrollYear = query.EnrollYear;
                student.Class = query.Class;
                student.City = query.City;
                student.Country = query.Country;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
            return student;
        }

        public bool AddNewStudent(StudentDataContract student)
        {
            try
            {
                Student std = ctx.Students.Create();
                std.Name = student.Name;
                std.Email = student.Email;
                std.Class = student.Class;
                std.EnrollYear = student.EnrollYear;
                std.City = student.City;
                std.Country = student.Country;

                ctx.Students.Add(std);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(StudentDataContract student)
        {
            try
            {
                int Stud_Id = Convert.ToInt32(student.StudentID);
                Student std = ctx.Students.Where(rec => rec.StudentID == Stud_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                std.Name = student.Name;
                std.Email = student.Email;
                std.Class = student.Class;
                std.EnrollYear = student.EnrollYear;
                std.City = student.City;
                std.Country = student.Country;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteStudent(string StudentId)
        {
            try
            {
                int Stud_Id = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
                Student std = ctx.Students.Where(rec => rec.StudentID == Stud_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                ctx.Students.Remove(std);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web.config file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp helpEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>


    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SchoolManagement.csdl|res://*/SchoolManagement.ssdl|res://*/SchoolManagement.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KHUNDOKARNIRJOR\KHUNDOKERNIRJOR;initial catalog=Student;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I can not access the from localhost its is always shows this error

Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

Here is Screen shot [image: Click here to see the out put]

Please any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see "services" element in your config file. Please take a look at the below link to configure your service.
[Configuring Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-services-using-configuration-files)

Another method is to create a wcf service using visual studio. Visual studio will generate appropriate config file for you. Then you can replace the methods, interface and configuration accordingly.

I see that you are trying to return a List. I don't think you can pass List as return parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check all methods on "
>   http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc" another suggestion, please
>   remove "/" from uriTemplate. Just write "GetAllStudent" instead of
>   "/GetAllStudent/".

Comment: sorry I change it but its responding same way

Comment: Rasel, please check your web config file as well. Service and behaviors tag is missing,

Answer (score 0):

```
> <services>
>       <service name="" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
>         <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
>       </service>
>     </services>
>     <behaviors>
>       <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
>           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
>           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
>         </behavior>
>       </serviceBehaviors>
>       <endpointBehaviors>
>         <behavior name="web">
>           <webHttp/>
>         </behavior>
>       </endpointBehaviors>
>     </behaviors>
```

As I look there is service and behaviors tags are missing from webconfig.